# Get a Range of cells within the same column to be pasted into a bullet point list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So, for my job, I have to create an open order report (OOR). I then create a word doc that highlights the "Key Points" of this report. So, when I run the Macro I've created for this report, I have the Key Points added to Sheet2 in the OOR spreadsheet.

I would then like these key points to be copied/pasted into MS Word in a bulleted list. So far, when running the macro, I can get a word doc opened and have it write out the title of the bulleted list, "Key points from file," but cannot get the bullet points added.

Please see the below code:

```
Selection.TypeText Text:="Key Points from the attached file: "
    With Selection
        .Font.Bold=True
        .Font.Color= RGB(31,73,125)
    End With
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
    With ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleBullet
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1    
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
    Selection.TypeText Text:= Worksheet(“Sheet2”).Range(“C2”).Value
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeText Text:= Worksheet(“Sheet2”).Range(“C3”).Value
    Selection.TypeParagraph
```

I am needing to do this for cells C2:C10.

Answer (score -1):

When writing macros the easiest way is to use the record macro button. Then see what it generates and use the VBA it generates.

Open Word, enable the developer ribbon (file | options | customise ribbon) and start recording a macro. Select some text and click the bullets button. Stop the macro and then you can see what the Word macro created in order to select the data and then format it.

Comment: The posted code does NOT make the bullets as the OP clearly stated as he asked the question to fix it! By recording a macro in word one will see the exact code used to make a selection bulleted. Then use this generated code which you know will create the bullets in the code above to fix it. If that doesn't work, then can look again, geez.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, that is exactly what I did to create the code listed in my post.

Comment: Can you step through the macro and see each step happening. I am unsure (without seeing it) if you have a selection for the bullets? Is the text selected you want to be bulleted? is your vbTab bit trying to indent the bullets or something else?